# Error when pushing to BigQuery tables containing lists and dics

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

The following code works in Google Colab but not on my local computer.

```py
import pandas as pd
from google.oauth2 import service_account

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['A'] = [[1], [2], [3]]

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info({--credential infos--},)

df.to_gbq(destination_table='raw.test', project_id='project-test', credentials = credentials, if_exists='replace')
```

The error I get is `pyarrow.lib.ArrowTypeError: Expected bytes, got a 'list' object`.

I have tried `google-cloud-bigquery` and `pandas-gbq` but get the same errors.

I'm running Python 3.10, Pandas 1.5.1. Google Colab runs Python 3.7 and Pandas 1.3.5.

Comment: Are you trying to make a Data Frame with lists under column `A`?  or do you want integers? for example `df['A'] = [1, 2, 3]`

Comment: It is a simplified example of what I need. I need lists and dictionaries as elements of my Data Frame.

Comment: I don't think gbq takes `list` [types](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#data_type_sizes), try converting to an np.array before hand like this:
`df['A'].apply(lambda x: np.array(x))`

Comment: I'm going to try your suggestion. However, the Data Frame is composed of information coming from web scraping, so it might be too resourceful to convert lists and dics to arrays. Also, why does it work within Colab with lists and not on my computer?

Comment: Are you sure the web scraping data is a `list`? could it be JSON that you are getting? because JSON is accepted by BigQuery

Comment: If I replace lists by dictionaries, I get a similar error: `pyarrow.lib.ArrowTypeError: Expected bytes, got a 'dict' object`

Comment: Google Query doe not take dictionaries either, I am pretty sure you are confusing JSON with python lists and dictionaries

Comment: Well, both work fine in Google Colab...

Comment: I wrote something more descriptive in the answers; a summary and an example

Answer (score 0):

Google BigQuery does not accepts python lists or dictionaries, [here is a list of the types it accepts](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#data_type_sizes).

I think you are confusing these types with JSON formatted strings (Note that ["JSON is purely a string with a specified data format — it contains only properties, no methods."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON#:%7E:text=JSON%20is%20purely%20a%20string%20with%20a%20specified%20data%20format%20%E2%80%94%20it%20contains%20only%20properties%2C%20no%20methods.))

This:

```
df.DataFrame()

df['A'] = ['[1]', '[2]', '[3]']
df['B'] = [[1], [2], [3]]

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     A    B
0  [1]  [1]
1  [2]  [2]
2  [3]  [3]
```

Looks the same but they are different.

This looks similar too, but again it is different:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame()

df_test['Python_Dictionary'] = [{"name": {"0": "banana"}, "color": {"0": "yellow"}}]
df_test['JSON'] =['{"name": {"0": "banana"}, "color": {"0": "yellow"}}']


print(type(df_test['Python_Dictionary'][0]))
print(type(df_test['JSON'][0]))
```

Prints:

```
<class 'dict'>
<class 'str'>
```

Check the data type of values you are using in Google Colab; that is, the data you are getting from your web-scrapping. Also try this in your computer if you want:

```
import pandas as pd
from google.oauth2 import service_account

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['A'] = ['[1]', '[2]', '[3]']

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info({--credential infos--},)

df.to_gbq(destination_table='raw.test', project_id='project-test', credentials = credentials, if_exists='replace')
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. However, as I said, it works on Colab without specifying the dtype of the elementes. Moreover, the same script works on Linux. I'm still looking to find what is going on.

Comment: It is curious. Have you tried the exact code you have above in Google Colab?  (not the one with the real web-scrapping data, the simplified version you posted above)